# Parse xhr data from a text file

Tags: r, import, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have text files that contains xhr data structured as such:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "record_id": 1,
            "birth_date": "2021-12-01T09:00:00.000Z",
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "mother": [
                {
                    "firstname": "Jane",
                    "lastname": "Doe"
                }
            ],
            "country": "USA",
            "country_code": 1
        },
        {
            "record_id": 2,
            "birth_date": "2021-12-01T09:02:00.000Z",
            "firstname": "Joe",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "mother": [
                {
                    "firstname": "Jane",
                    "lastname": "Doe"
                }
            ],
            "country": "USA",
            "country_code": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this a format that can be easily imported and structured with the likes of XML, httr, rvest or the like? Or do I need to manually read it in and parse myself with something like readr?

Once I know the best way to get it into R I can do the research to then extract/manipulate the data, but I'm not sure what's the best way to get it into R in the first place - especially if there is a webscraper function that can do most of the parsing automatically. TY

Comment: This is in JSON format.  See the jsonlite package to read the file.

Comment: Do you really have values like `country": USA,` without quotes around the USA? Because that's not allowed with JSON data which is going to make parsing these files much more difficult.

Comment: Dave ~ perfect exactly what I needed.

Comment: MrFlick ~  nope. Was simulating the data structure and put in dummy text and must have missed it . Thanks!